# Add record in related table ArcPad

Tags: arcpad, layers, lock

i have a layer form (named form_layer) containing a combobox and allows to add records into the related table, by showing a form  of the related table (named form_table)

When i try to add record showing first the layer form , then showing the form_table, the row is not saved when i click "ok" on the form_table (so i can't see the record in the combobox when just added despite the combobox is reloaded ) but until i go back to the form_layer and click ok.

i tried to show the form a toolbar button without calling a layer form, it works great :)

i dont know if there's an inner lock when displaying a form layer

any suggestion will be very helpful

Comment: Whats the relationship (relationship class settings)?  I seem to remember having this issue when trying to make relationships between feature classes rather than between a feature class and a related table.

Comment: there's no relationship between the tables that i'm talking about, the related table is not related with this featureclass but with other one

Comment: I'm confused: is this a related table, or just the attribute table of a feature class?

Comment: this is a related table to the feature class points(for eg), but i want to get their values on the Layer(polygons) form, i know that i have not respected the supposed database design  but this is due some arcpad limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve that in ArcPad, I think you have to do some programming within ArcPad Studio.

The available languages have been VBScript and Javascript, but I've heard them mention bringing Python on board at somepoint.

Essentially you have to access the data table field, copy it's value and apply it to the empty field in another feature class.  I'm trying to find their help files online, but I guess they're only avialable within the ArcPad Studio application, which I no longer have installed.

Here's a link of  [some ArcPad VBScript](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16477)   just to give you an idea of what you're up against, but it's not an exact solution.  You'll have to use the built-in help files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Roy, i've started using applets for adding record into feature class, so i avoided the layer_form which makes some problems, it's easy to use but it's hard for event customization.

so i could navigate between forms more easily.